# Pandas extract sublevels from column value and fill sublevel values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose this dataframe:

```
vals = [['1.00.00.00', 'Total Assets', 1000], ['1.01.00.00', 'Cash', 200], ['1.02.00.00', 'Inventory', 800], ['1.02.01.00', 'Goods in process', 300], ['1.02.02.00', 'Goods for sale', 500], ['2.00.00.00', 'Liabilities', 750], ['2.01.00.00', 'Commercial Liabilities', 700], ['2.02.00.00', 'Other liabilities', 50], ['3.00.00.00', 'Net equity', 250]]

cols = ['account', 'name', 'balance']

df = pd.DataFrame(valores, columns=cols)

df
```

[image]

So, every account from an above level sums the accounts from the inferior levels.

I would like to create columns that contain the name of the group of accounts for each level, a column that gets the account's level and if that is the ultimate level for that group of accounts. For clarity, this is the output I would like to get:

[image]

I have tried the following but I got stuck when I needed to read previous rows values somehow and I also got a FutureWarning error at one of the steps (`FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.`).

```
df['sub_account_1'], df['sub_account_2'], df['sub_account_3'], df['sub_account_4']\
= df['account'].str.split('.').str

df['clasif_1'], df['clasif_2'], df['clasif_3'], df['clasif_4'] = ("", "", "", "")

def account_level(df):
    if df['sub_account_2'] == '00':
        return '2'
    elif df['sub_account_3'] == '00':
        return '3'
    elif df['sub_account_4'] == '00':
        return '4'
    else:
        return np.nan

df['nivel_cuenta'] = df.apply(account_level, axis = 1)
```

Stopped there. I believe there has to be a more clever way to approach this, maybe a known way to do this being the case not that uncommon (accounts and subaccounts levels).

The real case scenario has up to 8 sublevels but the account code has the same structure. I would use the created columns to control the subtotals that are given in the original dataset and then do some analytics.

**Can anyone point me out in the right direction?**  (I would hate to go back to Excel for this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the data frame rows, and apply the conditions on sub_account_x == 0 to fill the desired columns

```
# initialize the sub_account columns and clasif columns
sub_account_cols = ['sub_account_1', 'sub_account_2', 'sub_account_3', 'sub_account_4']
clasif_cols = ['clasif_1', 'clasif_2', 'clasif_3', 'clasif_4']

# assign default values for new columns 
df['sub_account_1'] = df['sub_account_2'] = df['sub_account_3'] = df['sub_account_4'] = ''
df['clasif_1'] = df['clasif_2'] = df['clasif_3'] = df['clasif_4'] = np.NaN
df['level'] = 0


# iterate over the dataframe rows
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # check which sub_account part is 00 and assign that as the level and the clasif
    sub_accounts = row['account'].split('.')
    df.loc[idx, sub_account_cols] = sub_accounts # we really don't need to assign to sub_account_x columns here, if you dont want to populate the parent clasif columns with previous value as I have done in the groupby below
    for i, sub_account in enumerate(sub_accounts):
        if sub_account=='00':
            df.loc[idx, 'level'] = i
            df.loc[idx, 'clasif_' + str(i)] = row['name']
            break

# fill clasif for parent rows
for i, clasif_col in enumerate(clasif_cols):
    df[clasif_col] = df.groupby('sub_account_'+str(i+1))[clasif_col].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill')).fillna('')

# Fill last_level = True if the level of current row is greater than level of next row
df['last_level'] = np.where(df['level']>=df['level'].shift(-1), True, False)
# The last row is always the last level
df.loc[len(df)-1, 'last_level'] = True

# drop unwanted columns
df.drop(sub_account_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      account                    name  balance      clasif_1                 clasif_2          clasif_3 clasif_4  level  last_level  
0  1.00.00.00            Total Assets     1000  Total Assets                                                          1       False  
1  1.01.00.00                    Cash      200  Total Assets                     Cash                                 2        True  
2  1.02.00.00               Inventory      800  Total Assets                Inventory                                 2       False  
3  1.02.01.00        Goods in process      300  Total Assets                Inventory  Goods in process               3        True  
4  1.02.02.00          Goods for sale      500  Total Assets                Inventory    Goods for sale               3        True  
5  2.00.00.00             Liabilities      750   Liabilities                                                          1       False  
6  2.01.00.00  Commercial Liabilities      700   Liabilities   Commercial Liabilities                                 2        True  
7  2.02.00.00       Other liabilities       50   Liabilities        Other liabilities                                 2        True  
8  3.00.00.00              Net equity      250    Net equity                                                          1        True
```

Comment: This works and is very elegant code!  I am only getting a `FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases`.

Comment: You are right I was not clear about 'last_level'...  The logic is: if the account has no further sublevels, it is a 'last_level' account.

Comment: @nacode Here you go. I updated the last level logic

Comment: Several good ideas in your code... The use of `np.where` together with `.shift`.. this is something I need to learn right now.  The use of `enumerate` is also clever. And I am still figuring out how you were able to combine a `groupby` together with an `apply` and a `fillna` in the same line of code. That is just too advanced for me. So, yes, your answer was useful, it solves the problem, and I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to do what I needed with the following code. I mainly used some python for loops but I still feel there has to be a more 'pandas' way of doing this. I've tried several things based on other stackoverflow questions, but struggled a lot to achieve this in other ways. I'll leave the code here but feedback is appreciated and more ideas are welcome.

```
vals = [['1.00.00.00', 'Total Assets', 1800], ['1.01.00.00', 'Cash', 1000], ['1.02.00.00', 'Inventory', 900], ['1.02.01.00', 'Goods in process', 300], ['1.02.02.00', 'Goods for sale', 500], ['1.02.03.00', 'Goods other', 100], ['2.00.00.00', 'Liabilities', 900], ['2.01.00.00', 'Commercial Liabilities', 850], ['2.02.00.00', 'Other liabilities', 50], ['2.03.00.00', 'More liabilities', 20], ['2.03.01.00', 'One liability', 20], ['2.03.01.01', 'One-One liability', 20], ['2.03.01.02', 'One-Two liability', 20], ['2.03.02.00', 'Two liability', 20], ['2.04.00.00', 'One More liability', 20], ['3.00.00.00', 'Net equity', 250]]

cols = ['account', 'name', 'balance']

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)

level_cols = ['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3', 'level_4',]
df[level_cols] = df['account'].str.split('.',expand=True)

df['account_level'] = ""
df['imputable'] = ""

clasif_cols = ['clasif_1', 'clasif_2', 'clasif_3', 'clasif_4']

for col in clasif_cols:
    df[col] = ""

for i in range(len(df)):
    
    row = df.loc[i]
    account_level = 0
    
    if i == 0:
        account_level += 1
        df.loc[i, 'clasif_1'] = row['name']
    
    else:
        for level in range(4):
            
            level_col = "level_"+str(level+1)
            clasif_col = "clasif_"+str(level+1)

            if row[level_col] == '00':
                break
            else:
                account_level += 1
                prev_row = df.loc[i-1]
                
                # If row level is the same as previous value, repeat previous clasification. 
                # Else, assign name to this clasification
                if row[level_col] == prev_row[level_col]: 
                    df.loc[i, clasif_col] = prev_row[clasif_col]
                else: 
                    df.loc[i, clasif_col] = row['name']
                
    df.loc[i, 'account_level'] = account_level

for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.loc[i]
    # If this is the last row, it is an imputable account for sure. Also needed it to avoid an error at last row.

    if i == (len(df)-1):
        df.loc[i, 'imputable'] = "YES"
    # else, if the level of this row is equal or higher than the level of the next row, this is an imputable account
    else:
        next_row = df.loc[i+1]
        if row['account_level'] >= next_row['account_level']:
            df.loc[i, 'imputable'] = "YES"

df.drop(level_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

df
```

Output:

[image]